# replace html <br> elements with linebreaks using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

say i've a java script string 
`var str = "first line <br /> second line"`
i want to output it on html, how can i do that?
i want the out put to be something like this

**first line**

**second line**

Comment: Where are you trying to output the replaced string? Remember that if you are reinjecting the replaced string in HTML the `\n` will of course not work. Can you give us an example of how you want to use the replaced string?

Comment: I would also add that there's no reason to use a regex expression when you know the exact string to replace. `'<br>'` in your case would suffice as the first parameter.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/danujazoji/1/edit?js,console — It works fine when I test it

Comment: yes i want to output the replaced string in html, but without having the <br> tags

Comment: White space will be collapsed in HTML, so you may be correctly changing the text, but not seeing the results as you expect. In which case you'll need to edit the question to show where you are displaying the output.

Comment: say for example i've this string in javascript "this is <br> new line" i want to replace the <br> with a line break and output it in html having a line break

Comment: @aymantarig — `<br>` is how you write a line break in HTML. It's very hard to understand what the problem is. Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: say i've a java script string ```var str = "first line <br /> second line"``` i want to output it on html, how can i do that ?

Comment: @aymantarig — You implied that you were already doing that but not getting the result you wanted. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: here's a link to the app I'm working on https://ayman-tarig.github.io/notebook/ and here you can see the codes https://github.com/Ayman-Tarig/notebook try to add a note that have a line breaks and when you click on it's title to read it, the linebreaks wil not be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED (according to OP's last comment) - If you wish to output text from javascript to html, in this case there is no need to replace BRs:

HTML part:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript part:

```js
var str = "<p> This is the first line <br /> And this is the second line <br /> </p>";

//str = str.replace(/\<br \/\>/g, "\r\n");

var element = document.getElementById('output');
element.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

Original answer (BR to \r\n):

Well, you could replace `<br />` this way:

```js
   var str = "<p> This is the first line <br /> And this is the second line <br /> </p>";
str = str.replace(/\<br \/\>/g, "\r\n");
alert(str);
```

Comment: This works fine on javascript but when i take the string back to html it doesn't work n

Comment: @aymantarig That happens because \r\n applies to plain text, not HTML markup.

Comment: say i've a java script string var str = "first line <br /> second line" i want to output it on html, how can i do th

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio why you provided `JSFiddle` for snipped code while you can provide it by StackOverFlow editor.

Comment: @Aria My bad. It's old habits, plus I never got really used to work with Stackoverflow editor.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio,It is very easy to use, I just edited it see the output.

Comment: @Aria Thank you :) Although I must say, the alert msg inside stackoverflow looks pretty scary

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>


    <p id="test">Muhammed</p>

    <script>
    var str = "first line <br /> second line";
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = str;
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```